# the get name and model of the system processor "cpu" in the inject content script in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I get the name and model of the system processor `CPU` in the inject content script?
Is there a way to access `chrome.system.cpu` in inject content script?

I saw this code from David Christian who wrote in the `popup.js` file that it works but I do not know how I can access its function in the inject content script.
Please help me.

```js
// David Christian

// System info Chrome extension
var systemInformation = {
  requestInfo: function() {
        chrome.system.cpu.getInfo(function (cpuInfo){
            var elem = document.getElementById('cpu');

            var info = cpuInfo.modelName + "<br>";
            info += "Architecture: " + cpuInfo.archName + "<br>";
            info += "Cores: " + cpuInfo.numOfProcessors.toString() + "<br>";
            // info += "Features: " + cpuInfo.features + "<br>";

            info += "<table><tr><th>#</th><th>User (ms)</th><th>Kernel (ms)</th><th>Idle (ms)</th><th>Total (ms)</th></tr>";

            for (var i=0; i < cpuInfo.processors.length; i++){
                info += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td>";
                info += "<td>" + cpuInfo.processors[i].usage.user + "</td>";
                info += "<td>" + cpuInfo.processors[i].usage.kernel + "</td>";
                info += "<td>" + cpuInfo.processors[i].usage.idle + "</td>";
                info += "<td>" + cpuInfo.processors[i].usage.total + "</td><tr>";
            }

            elem.innerHTML = info + "</table>";
        });

        chrome.system.memory.getInfo(function (ramInfo){
            var elem = document.getElementById('ram');
            elem.innerHTML = (ramInfo.availableCapacity / 1073741824).toFixed(2)
                                       + "gb / " + Math.round(ramInfo.capacity / 1073741824).toFixed(2)
                                       + "gb (" + ((ramInfo.availableCapacity / ramInfo.capacity) * 100.0).toFixed(2).toString() + "% available)";
        });
  }
};

// Start getting system data as soon as page is ready..
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Ensure that we have a display straight away
  systemInformation.requestInfo();

  // Update the display every 3 seconds
  setInterval(systemInformation.requestInfo, 3000);
});
```

Comment: No, there's no direct access but you can do it in the background script and [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the content script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Is it possible to write the sample code?